# list.addAll(___). How can I properly populate my list?

Tags: java

Basically I am aiming to do:

. Create a new ArrayList.

. Place my keys inside.

First part is finally working flawlessly. Second part isn't. I'm having a lot of trouble with the error messages so I'm not even sure where to start. I was hoping someone could help me figure out the proper way to populate this ArrayList or give me a better way to gather the information I'm attempting to do.

```
  try
  {
     fw = new FileWriter(new File("Report.txt"));  

     //HashMap<String, Statistics> statistics;
     Set<String> keys = statistics.keySet();

     for (String i : keys)
     {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + statistics.get(i));
        System.out.println(i + ": " + inventoryName); 
     }

     List<Statistics> list = new ArrayList<Statistics>();
     list.addAll(keys);

     for(String i : list)
     {

     }
     fw.close(); 
  }
```

Errors:

```
Inventory.java:255: error: no suitable method found for addAll(Set<String>)
       list.addAll(keys);
           ^
method Collection.addAll(Collection<? extends Statistics>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; Set<String> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Statistics>)
method List.addAll(Collection<? extends Statistics>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; Set<String> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Statistics>)
Inventory.java:257: error: incompatible types: Statistics cannot be converted to String
     for(String i : list)
                    ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
2 errors
```

Comment: Your 2nd list stores `Statistics`, so you probably want [HashMap.values()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of `keys()`; either that, or change your `List<Statistics>` to `List<string>` - but it wouldn't be different from `keys`..

Comment: Your `List<Statistics> list` is meant to hold Statistics, but you are trying to add to it Strings. How do you imagine it working?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the `entrySet`. For performance reasons, I'd recommend a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). Something like,

```
Map<String, Statistics> statistics = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// ...
List<Statistics> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Statistics> entry : statistics.entrySet()) {
  list.add(entry.getValue());
}
```